# Reverse playback audio file in ios objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, reverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reverse an audio file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593118/how-to-reverse-an-audio-file)

Is there any way/library in objective-c to make the audio file in reverse order.

Actually in my application user record his voice and then change the recording in various sounds. Now I have to use the reverse voice.

Please suggest me what should I do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve such feature on audio file.

My suggestion to do this is to crearte chunks of audio files and merge them in reverse orderin one audio file.

You can use `AVMutableComposition`,`AVMutableCompositionTrack`,`AVAssetExportSession` APIs to achieve this.

You can also get more help from [trimming movie file](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH7-SW4) mentioned in Apple documents and same you can do for audio file.

Comment: Here is a thread with even more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707998/ios-audio-manipulation

Comment: thanks for the help... is there any code example to do this